# Bash tar and output to log file

Tags: bash, tar, bash-scripting

How can i write TAR operation in to a log file?

```
tar -czvf arh.tar.gz public_html > 1.log
```

TAR -czvf worked thanks guys!

Now in bash script:

```
for i in */ ; do
    sitefolder="$HOME/domains/${i%%/}/public_html"
    if [ -d "$sitefolder" ]
    then
        ( tar -czvf $tbackups/$i".tar.gz" public_html >> $logs/backups.log ; )
    fi
done
```

How can i make output in a log file like:

domain.com successfully archived
domain1.com successfully archived
and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key issue is that

```
tar -czf arh.tar.gz public_html 1
```

doesn't create any output at all. So you need at least

```
tar -czvf arh.tar.gz public_html 1
```

to create any output. But as the output goes to STDERR instead of STDOUT you will need

```
tar -czvf arh.tar.gz public_html 1 2> 1.log
```

to catch any output in the log file

---

It's usually better to ask new questions instead of following-up in the same topic but here we go

```
for i in */ ; do
    sitefolder="$HOME/domains/${i%%/}/public_html"
    if [ -d "$sitefolder" ]; then
        echo "Backing up ${i%%/}" >> $logs/backups.log
        tar -czvf $tbackups/$i".tar.gz" public_html 2>> $logs/backups.log
        echo "Backup of ${i%%/} successfull" >> $logs/backups.log
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks now it works, can u look at my updated post please.

Comment: do i need on this line tar -czvf $tbackups/$i".tar.gz" public_html 2>> $logs/backups.log - output to a log file?

Comment: @Heihachi only if you want to log each file as it gets added to the archive

Answer (score 2):

```
tar czvf arh.tar.gz public_html 1 >1.log 2>&1
```

I added a `v` so it's verbose, ie it will output the list of files/dirs it is tarring, and this will go into `1.log`.

Are you sure you want to tar both `public_html` and a file/directory named `1` ? Because that's what is written

I also took out the `-` in front of the options (tar is compatible with very old versions of that command, that didn't use `-`, so it interprets the first argument it receives as options by default. It's a bit more compatible that way.